# wiki forbidden message on specific words

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

I have a weird situation regarding this wiki: 
http://www.dvartora.com/Wiki/en/index.php?title=TestPage

This wiki is version 1.16.0

If I add the word "free"(so it will write: "Avast! Free Antivirus"(without quotes)) between the 2 words and try to save it says I am forbidden.

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /Wiki/en/index.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error
>   was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.

You can try it for yourself to see the result.

During installation I had a problem, that I bypassed doing a local install and uploading to the server, that it said I am forbidden(the same error).

Comment: Isn't this just a spam filter? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Spam#Edit_filtering

Comment: Treffynnon - I don't have the $wgSpamRegex var in my LocalSettings.php file. That means I don't have that filtered. right?(If I understood correctly the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I added the word "free" **[successfully](http://www.dvartora.com/Wiki/en/index.php?title=TestPage&action=historysubmit&diff=8&oldid=7)**. However, "Free Antivirus" does not work but "[Free stuff](http://www.dvartora.com/Wiki/en/index.php?title=TestPage&action=historysubmit&diff=9&oldid=8)" does.

Looking at the [version](http://www.dvartora.com/Wiki/en/index.php?title=Special%3aVersion) they have no unusual extensions added.

So it seems likely that Treffynnon is correct - but I can't find the functionality. =:-(

Comment: The problem isn't the word "free" but its context to "Free Antivirus". I am aware that the word free alone works. That is why I wrote the phrase in my question